# Class com.sonicsw.sonicmq.j2ee.jmsra.impl.sonic.SonicManagedXAQueueConnectionFactory class is from which Jar if anyboady know?

Tags: jms, jndi, message-queue, esb, middleware

I am working on SONIC ESB middleware where i need to get SonicManagedXAQueueConnectionFactory object from another server using JNDI but getting following error.

```
An exception occurred while trying to instantiate the ManagedConnectionFactory class com.sonicsw.sonicmq.j2ee.jmsra.impl.sonic.SonicManagedXAQueueConnectionFactory used by resource jms/DemoSSBConnectionFactory : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sonicsw.sonicmq.j2ee.jmsra.impl.sonic.SonicManagedXAQueueConnectionFactory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just missing one jar file I got the jar file its `sonic-jms-ra.jar`